# git clone fatal error - repository 'https' does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, https, centos

I am trying to get a git clone of a github repo, namely odoo (formerly OpenERP). When trying to run the git clone command in Centos 8, I get the following error:
[error as shown in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YYhJ.png)

I am running this command in root. I have tried running it as sudo.

The machine is running in a VPS, and seems to have https resolving issues. I can't ping google through https for instance. I also checked, and there is no firewall causing issues. [https ping attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0nij.png)

How do I best approach this? I'm not sure if it is a name server issue or the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git --depth 1 -b 13.0`

Ping requires only hostname, not a URL. Try pinging `ping google.com`

Comment: Both were tried, and sadly it still doesn't work. It keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: you are using `;` instead of `:`, copy paste the command it will work

Comment: That did the trick! A classic case of looking past the obvious and trying to find a much more difficult issue. Turns out it's just a keyboard problem.  Thanks arryph!